# Convert/Encrypt Office 2003 Documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, encryption

We have a large number (1000s) of old Excel 2003 spreadsheets that we need to encrypt.  The encryption in Excel 2003 is outdated now so we would like to update the files to 2010 format and then encrypt them.  I am trying to find a script or program to do this but I haven't been able to.  The only thing I have found is the Microsoft Migration Planning Toolkit which includes the OFC tool.  The problem is that this converts to the 2007 format which, while it is compatible, is not the same as the 2010 format.  The 2007 format encryption uses the weaker EBC block chaining instead of the CBC method that 2010 uses.  Also, opening a 2007 file in 2010 will then ask to save the file even if no changes are made (presumably to update it to the newer format).

Comment: It sounds like this task is a good reason to write a small program that uses the Excel COM library, allowing you to open/save a file, would be simple enough to just loop through each file.

Comment: Like Ramhound said, you could create a small program.. or you can also write one in VBA that would open an external Excel file, save it, and do whatever else you need.  There are many examples out there to do what you are asking in VBA so take a look and if you have any problems post back and I will help you out.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a Powershell script that does just what you both described.  One thing I have noticed though is that opening/saving is not the same as opening/converting.  Even in Excel, if I do an open/save as and then do an open/convert for the same document I will get two different outputs (unziped the docs and compared the xml files).  Can a convert operation be done in COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Powershell to automate the conversion.  Here is my script for anyone interested:

```
function ConvertTo-XLSX {

<#
.SYNOPSIS
XLS files within a provided path are recursively enumerated and convert to XLSX files.
.DESCRIPTION
XLS files within a provided path are recursively enumerated and convert to XLSX files.
The original XLS files remain intact, a new XLSX file will be created.
.PARAMETER Path
This parameter takes the input of the path where the XLS files are located.
.PARAMETER Visible
Using the parameter will show you how Excel does the work. Not using the parameter will enable Excel 
to accomplish its tasks in the background.
Note: By not using this parameter you will be able to convert some XLS files which have corruptions 
in them, when using the parameter and therefor the Excel GUI will give you an error.
.PARAMETER ToFolder
This parameter enables you to provide a location where the file is saved. When this parameter is 
not used, the file will be saved as an XLS file in the same location as where the 
original XLS file is located.
.PARAMETER Password
If specified, the password will be used to encrypt the converted Excel document.  Passwords are case
sensitive and must be less than 15 characters long.
.PARAMETER Force
If specified, then files that have already been converted (there is already a file with the same name
but a .xlsx extension in the output directory) will be re-converted.
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012'
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012' -Visible
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012' -ToFolder 'D:\Data\2012XLSX'
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012' -Visible -ToFolder 'D:\Data\2012XLSX'
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012' -Password 'SecureP@ssword'
.EXAMPLE
ConvertTo-XLSX -Path 'D:\Data\2012' -Force
#>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$Path,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$Visible,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$ToFolder,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$Password,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][switch]$Force
    )
    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
        $xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
        Write-Verbose 'Opening Excel COM object.'
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
        if ($Visible -eq $true) {
          $Excel.visible = $true
        } else {
          $Excel.visible = $false
          $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
          $Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false
          $Excel.UserControl = $false
          $Excel.Interactive = $false
        }
        $filetype = "*xls"
    } process {
        if (Test-Path -Path $Path) {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include '*.xls' -recurse | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Verbose "Processing $($_.Basename)"
                if ($ToFolder -ne '') {
                    $FilePath = Join-Path $ToFolder $_.BaseName
                    $FilePath += ".xlsx"
                } else {
                    $FilePath = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
                    $FilePath += ".xlsx"
                }
                if (!(Test-Path $FilePath) -Or $Force) {
                  Write-Verbose "Opening $($_.Basename)"
                  $WorkBook = $Excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)
                  Write-Verbose "Saving $($_.Basename) to $FilePath with password $Password"
                  $WorkBook.saveas($FilePath, $xlFixedFormat, $Password)
                  Write-Verbose "Closing $($_.Basename)"
                  $WorkBook.close()
                } else {
                  Write-Verbose "$($_.Basename) already converted."
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 'No path provided or access has been denied.'
        }
    } end {
        Write-Verbose 'Closing Excel'
        $Excel.Quit()
        $Excel = $null
        [gc]::collect()
        [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
}
```

This was based on a script by Jeff Wouters found here: http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2013/10/powershell-function-to-convert-xls-files-to-xlsx/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look into a scripting languages such as [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).  The scripting language will replicate the actions that a user would take including mouse and keyboard input. You will be able to set it up to convert the files based on a list or location.

Comment: Interesting.  I will have to try this out and see what the performance is like.  I have literally 1000s of spreadsheets to do.